# What makes images pop up at the top of some Google web search results?

Tags: google-search, search-results

For example, when I search for "hbo series" I get the results below.

Is this something HBO has configured that any other site could also do, or something that Google itself decides to do for certain common searches?  If the latter, what criteria does Google use to do it?

[image: Google Search displays a list of HBO series, showing their covers, titles, and years]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [searchenginewatch.com](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2299454/4-Google-Carousel-Optimization-Tips):

> -Set up a Google Places for Business and Google+ page. This post outlines the most important aspects of both services, and explains how
>   to merge the two types of pages for a single business.
>
> -Make sure images are high resolution, unique, and order them in terms of your priority.
>
> -Encourage happy customers to review your business on Google. Research shows that reviews play a significant role of placement in the
>   carousel.
>
> -Measure performance and establish a new baseline.

Comment: These tips seem to be relevant to The Google local 'Carousel'. This type of Carousel is not 'Local' related and is part of the Google knowledge Graph, so most of those tips aren't really relevant.